# Deriving A implies B from Not A

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My logic textbook has the following example showing how to derive $A \to B$ from $\neg A$:

First we assume $A$ and use the conjunction introduction rule which results in a contradiction $[A] \land \neg A$. Now we can use the negation introduction rule to get $\neg \neg B$. With the negation elimination rule we get $B$ and after using the implication introduction rule we have $A \to B$.

However, I'm confused when it comes to using the negation introduction rule to get $\neg \neg B$ from $A \land \neg A$. While $A \land \neg A$ is clearly a contradiction resulting from our (temporary) assumption $A$, shouldn't this result the opposite of our assumption, that is $\neg A$, being true? Where does the $\neg \neg B$ come from? Quoting my textbook: "When we have derived a contradiction $B \land \neg B$ from the temporary assumption $A$, we consider $\neg A$ proved."

Comment: $A\to B$ means $\neg A \vee B$, since we have $\neg A$, therefore $\neg A \vee B$ certainly holds.

Comment: Taking my first steps on propositional logic, I completely missed that. What you said is obviously true. Do you have any idea why did the textbook present such a longwinded example when there's a lot more concise proof without the negation introduction rule available? Is the textbook example even correct (deriving $\neg \neg B$ from $[A] \land \neg A$)?

Comment: To be honest it looks to me like mezhang doesn't know what a formal deductive system is.

Comment: @GitGud You are right, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: @user1704650 What book is that?

Comment: @GitGud It's called "Logic One" and is available for free: [link](http://mathstat.helsinki.fi/logic/LogicOneText.pdf). There are also open WEPS courses available using that ebook. The example I'm talking about is 1.8.6 on page 45.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not having the proof in front of me, I can't really comment on the proof you are referring to, as a whole, as I can only conclude that you are perhaps mixing up proofs?

Your post begins by stating that you are concerned about a proof in your text about *deducing* $A\rightarrow B$ *from* the premise $\lnot A$. And you start by suggesting that the proof proceeds by making the assumption $A$.  With this assumption, together with the premise $\lnot A$, we have conjunction introduction to get $A \land \lnot A$.

But then you go on to discuss $\lnot \lnot B$, and in your second paragraph, refer to the result of having proved $\lnot A$. What I'm confused about is why set out to prove $A \implies B$, **given** $\lnot A$, and conclude, $\lnot A$ is therefore true?

What I suspect your text is proving is something like the following:

1. $\lnot A\quad \text{premise}$
2. $\;\;\;*\;\;A\quad \text{assumption}$
3. $\;\;\;*\;\;*\;\;\lnot B\quad\text{assumption}$
4. $\;\;\;*\;\;*\;\;A \land \lnot A \quad\text{$1, 2$, conjunction introduction}$
5. $\;\;\;*\;\;\lnot\lnot B \quad\text{$3, 4$, negation introduction}$
6. $\;\;\;*\;\;B\quad\quad\text{$5$, negation elimination}$
7. $A\rightarrow B \quad\text{$2-6$, conditional introduction}$

Note that following $(4)$, having derived a contradiction, namely $A \land \lnot A$, we can deny any assumption occuring prior to the contradiction.

---

However, we can alternatively start with the given premise, $\lnot A$.  By *disjunction introduction* $\lnot A \lor B$ then follows. But $$\lnot A \lor B \equiv A\rightarrow B,$$ thus proving that from $\lnot A$ we can derive $A \rightarrow B$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With "proof" I'm referring to the deduction in the question's second paragraph ("First we assume A"...).

Comment: I agree that the second alternative is preferable to your text's approach!!

Comment: Thank you for your edit, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I was confused about how "falsity implies anything" because it seemed so unintuitive - as if I could have proved almost anything from any premises. Now I see that the discharging of the assumption $A$ at step 6 is crucial for the proof to be valid. You can indeed "prove" almost anything from any premises if you don't discharge the assumptions - but then you haven't really proven anything at all (because the assumptions become premises for your proof).

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help...I certainly understand the unintuitiveness :-)

Comment: "Note that following (3), having derived a contradiction, namely A∧¬A, then anything can be asserted in line (4): It seems your text chose to assert the denial of ¬B. We might just have well directly asserted B."

Not quite.  The assertion of $\lnot$ B has a different scope than when we get B.

Comment: @amWhy: Wow, you've been busy, very nice answer! =1

Comment: The second argument here relies on the equivalence of (¬A∨B) and (A→B), as well as a equivalence elimination rule which says something like "from p and (p≡q), we can infer q."

Comment: Yes indeed, @Doug. It was/is simply an informal argument sketching how one might proceed differently.

Answer (score 1):

A negation introduction rule often means that from a contradiction we can infer the negation of the proposition that we've assumed.  So, I think your textbook aims at some proof like this (note the difference with amWhy's proof):

1 $\lnot$ A assumption

2 |  A assumption

3 || $\lnot$ B assumption

4 || (A $\land$ $\lnot$ A) 1, 2 conjunction introduction

5 | $\lnot$ $\lnot$ B 3-4 negation introduction

6 | B 5 negation elimination

7 (A $\implies$ B) 3-6 conditional introduction

The $\lnot$ $\lnot$ B comes from assuming $\lnot$ B, deriving a contradiction, and then using negation introduction.

Comment: Is the difference in that you're making the assumption $\neg B$ explicitly while amWhy is not? As far as I understood the amWhy's proof, the step 4 is kind of using the $\neg B$ assumption and would discharge it if it would "exist", it is just not explicitly written out? So that your proofs would essentially be the very same excepts yours is arguably a bit easier to read? The textbook's example is written the same way as is amWhy's proof so I'm inclined to think it's not necessarily "wrong".

Comment: @user1704650 Yes, that's the difference.  I don't understand how the textbook does what you say it does... a formal proof has to follow specific rules or it's not a formal proof.  What does the negation introduction rule in your textbook say exactly?

Comment: [Logic One](http://mathstat.helsinki.fi/logic/LogicOneText.pdf) page 44, "1.8.3 Introducing negation". I don't see how it's justifying to leave out the assumption. It just says the following at the 1.8.6 example: "We could eliminate the assumption $\neg B$, if we had made this temporary assumption, but we did not."

Comment: @user1704650 I don't see how you can leave out the assumption ¬B legitimately here also.  Sometimes these texts do make errors.

Answer (score 0):

Again (I did this for another (great!) answer by `amWhy` already) I am giving an alternative representation of `amWhy`'s proof that makes all assumptions much more explicit. I did this here for myself anyway (to *truly* understand this proof), so I just tex'd it.

Format:
col 1 = assumptions,
col 2 = line number,
col 3 = derived formula,
col 4 = the numbers used are all line numbers, except for numbers in "[]", which are the assumption numbers that get discharged

We want to show: $\neg A \vdash A \rightarrow B$
\begin{align*}
1     & &(1) & &\neg A           & &A\\
2     & &(2) & &A                & &A\\
1,2   & &(3) & &\bot             & &\neg{}E\  1,2\\
1,2   & &(4) & &\neg \neg B      & &\neg{}I\  3[]\\
1,2   & &(5) & &B                & &\neg\neg{}E\ 4\\
1   & &(6) & &A\rightarrow B   & &\rightarrow{}I\ 5[2]
\end{align*}

In the above proof there are two things to note:
1. The negation elimination in line (4) discharges an assumption that was not explicitly made, thus the empty parentheses. Alternatively, we could have made an assumption 3 $\neg B$ and then discharged this assumption. Both variants are complelety equivlant, the one shown is just shorter.
2. Just like in all the orher proofs provides here, we cannot introduce B directly, but not B, as the only rule that allows us to infer something from a contradiction (i.e., $\bot$) is negation introdcution. Well, and not surprisingly, this rule has to introduce a negation... So we introduce a negation to negated B thus later leading to B.

Comment: Well, you can introduce $B$ directly *if* you have a rule of Explosion (aka *Ex Falso Quodlibet*)...$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~\neg A}{\fitch{~~2.~A\qquad\mathrm H}{~~3.~\bot\qquad\neg\mathrm E~(1,2)\\~~4.~B\qquad\mathrm X~(3)}\\~~5.~A\to B\quad\to\mathrm I~(2{-}4)}$$

Comment: Sure. I guess this rule (X) is nothing else than the concatenation/combination of the elementary proofs used above, i.e., $\neg I$ which introduces a negative proposition in a negated way (thus is double negative) plus  $\neg\neg E$ to end up in the positive proposition.

Comment: However, *Ex Falso Quodlibet* is considered to be intuitionistically valid, unlike double negation elimination.

Comment: Interesting. So I guess double-negative-elimination does not exist in logics where we do not have the rule of the excluded middle. So you are saying that in such logicsthe rule Ex Falso Quodlibet still exists? If so: interesting!